# Virtual keyboard not working properly for Entry in TableView - [Android]

Tags: xamarin, tableview

#### Description

I am using Entry in TableView and displaying the formatted value in focus. In this case virtual keyboard not showing while change focus within Entry.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Run the sample
2. Focus the 1st Entry
3. Focus 2nd Entry
4. Unfocus both views
5. Focus 2st Entry. See the keyboard not showing.

Sometimes while unfocus both Entry, keyboard not getting collapsed.

#### Basic Information

- Version with issue: 4.8.0.1451
- Platform Target Frameworks:
- Android: Nexus 6 Marshmallow 6.0 - API 23 emulator.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="EntryWithTableView.MainPage">

    <TableView>
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection >
                <ViewCell >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Focused="entry1_Focused" Unfocused="entry1_Unfocused"
                               x:Name="entry1" Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="100"/>
                        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Focused="entry1_Focused" Unfocused="entry1_Unfocused"
                               Grid.Column="2" x:Name="entry2" WidthRequest="100"/>


                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>

            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>

    </TableView>

</ContentPage>

[C#]:

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        double value = 5;

        private void entry1_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            Entry entry = sender as Entry;

            if(entry != null)
            {
                entry.Text = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void entry1_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            Entry entry = sender as Entry;

            if (entry != null)
            {
                entry.Text = value.ToString("F");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It caused by the **TableView** . You could use Grid as the root layout directly .

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Focused="entry1_Focused" Unfocused="entry1_Unfocused"
                               x:Name="entry1" Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="100" />
        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Focused="entry1_Focused" Unfocused="entry1_Unfocused"
                               Grid.Column="2" x:Name="entry2" WidthRequest="100"/>


    </Grid>
```

If you want to display a collection , you could use **ListView** .

Comment: We have to use TableView for some other functionalities. So please suggest the solution with TableView